# Does React State stores Style parameters?

Tags: reactjs, styles, state

I'm trying to wrap my head around React and I read in this article (https://medium.com/better-programming/react-hooks-vs-classes-add2676a32f2) that "In simple terms, state is simply an object that contains all your key-value pairs. State determines how your components render and behave".

Does that mean that state actually stores the component style parameters for instance?

Comment: The state of your class component can store the component style attribute of your divs. Then if you modify the state, it will also modify the style but only if this style attribute use the state object.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it does not.

Maybe author meant that by changing state you can control different things, like what part of component you should render or which css class to apply.

But state, does not matter what you use, class `setState` or `useState` hooks, only store whatever you set it to store.